# Таймаут функции Get в VBA скрипте Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Возникла необходимость считывать данные из COM порта в Excel. При помощи Get считываю байты в цикле, но возникает проблема. Если в какой-то момент данные перестают передаваться через COM порт, то Get подвешивает скрипт. Есть ли возможность прервать ожидание оператора Get по таймауту?
Пример кода:

```
Dim COMByte As Byte
Open "COM8:115200,N,8,1" For Binary Access Read As #1
For i = 1 To 10
    Get #1, , COMByte
    Debug.Print Chr(COMByte)
Next
Close #1
```

Comment: покажите фрагмент кода

Comment: Можно пробросить через `CreateObject("ScriptControl")` но много тонкостей. Примерно так http://www.wpuniverse.com/vb/showthread.php?35313-ScriptControl-Another-Method-to-run-VBScript-Code плюс - у sriptcontrol есть свойство timeout.

Comment: Как я понял, ScriptControl работает только в 32 битной версии Office. А у меня предполагается использование только на 64 битном.

Answer (score 0):

Прерывание - `DoEvents`

Пример, демонстрирующий временную задержку:

```
Sub jjj()
Dim t As Date
Dim i As Long
    t = Now

    For i = 1 To 1000000
        DoEvents

        If Format(Now - t, "s") > 5 Then
            MsgBox "Finish", 64, ""
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно о каких функциях вы говорите.

Тем не менее, работа с COM-портом в VBA достигается через WinApi и как следствие, я предполагаю, что функция "Get" является оберткой над ним.

В WinApi из COM-порта можно читать данные небольшими блоками.

Если вам доступен код этой обертки, то измените его так, что бы можно было задать возможность сколько байтов за раз считывать, а снаружи сделайте какой-нибудь таймер, что бы он не читал очередной блок, когда время иссякло.

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос примером кода. И да, я ошибся. Get - это оператор, а не функция.

Comment: Ну ты, как я понимаю читаешь по 1 байту. Так вот, в свой цикл засунь анализ таймаута.

Comment: Мне не понятно, как это сделать? В приведенном коде, если устройство послало в COM порт, например, всего 3 байта, то на четвертой итерации цикл просто будет висеть на строке с Get. Как я понимаю, этот оператор не отдаст управление циклу, пока не прочитает байт.

Comment: А разве ком порты не передают в конце стоп-символ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889507/how-do-i-detect-when-a-serial-port-has-been-closed-by-the-device-in-java/24342370

Comment: Нет, в моем случае это простейший однонаправленный UART. Там нет ни DTR/DSR, ни RTS/CTS. Устройство просто считывает неопределенное количество объектов и по каждому выдает в COM порт цифровую последовательность, заканчивающуюся символом CR. Я не могу знать заранее, сколько байт мне пошлет устройство. Поэтому, только таймаут. Нашел как реализуется таймаут в VB для .NET, но в Excel такое не работает.